# socket.io returns ipv6 and php return ipv4 : how to get consistently the same ip?

Tags: php, websocket, socket.io

My nodejs / socket.io returns ipv6:

```
IP = socket.request.connection.remoteAddress;
```

And my PHP returns ipv4

```
$IP = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']
```

Question: how can I make socket.io and php make work consistently (either both ipv4 or both ipv6) ?

Comment: Well this would imply that either: A) Whatever's fronting the PHP application is not listening on an IPv6 address. B) Whatever hostname you're using for the PHP app does not have an AAAA record. C) The hostname has A and AAAA and the client app is preferring IPv4. Or vice-versa for the Node app.

Comment: ok, but how to fix it ?

Comment: Start by figuring out which of those scenarios it actually is first of all ...?